# Can JMeter had the ability to get the CPU utilization for Nodejs

Tags: node.js, server, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

Can JMeter had the ability to get the CPU utilization for Nodejs. JMeter was very good for web testing and actually I need to have CPU utilization and other server information. Does Jmeter able to support for Nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Jmeter does not have a native way of recording metrics such as CPU/memory. However, this can be done using [this plugin](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/). It uses PerfMon to grab metrics from a tested server.